# how to link two java classes(for UI) each with their own main method

Tags: java

I am a newbie here and I was working on a desktop user interface in Java for an application. ...However i created 6 different interfaces that should be able to link to one another ... Each of the interfaces run individually as they have their own main method. .. and every tutorial and Web research lead to " how to link one main class and one sub class ". ...my question is is it possible to link two java classes each with its own main method??? If so can someone please guide me to incorporate it in my code ???
One of the interfaces is as follows ..

```
//start
/*
 * To change this license header, choose     
 License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose  
 Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
  */

 package spackage;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.border.Border;
 import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class Path2_Test1 extends       
javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form Path2_Test1 */
public Path2_Test1() {
    //create a panel for the 4 buttons
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1,0,20));
    p2.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));
    //add buttons to be customized later
    JButton addDoc = new JButton("ADD  
    DOCUMENT");
    JButton viewDb = new JButton("VIEW 
    DATABASE");
    JButton ask = new JButton("ASK");
    JButton about = new JButton("ABOUT");
    // set color


addDoc.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));

viewDb.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));
    ask.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));
    about.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));
    // add border        

    Border lineBorder = new   
 LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 3);
    addDoc.setBorder(lineBorder);
    viewDb.setBorder(lineBorder);
    ask.setBorder(lineBorder);
    about.setBorder(lineBorder);
    //set foreground color

    addDoc.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    viewDb.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    ask.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    about.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    // add to panel
    p2.add(addDoc);
    p2.add(viewDb);
    p2.add(ask);
    p2.add(about);


    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    // new border layout with hgap =5 and   
 vgap =10
    p1.setLayout(new 
BorderLayout(50,50));
    p1.setBackground(Color(217,63,49));
    //add north, ease, west, and south  
buttons with no labels to make a rigid   
 space
    p1.add(new JLabel(""),   
BorderLayout.EAST);
    p1.add(new JLabel(""),    
BorderLayout.WEST);
    p1.add(new JLabel(""), 
BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p1.add(new JLabel(""), 
BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p1.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add contents to the frame
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }

   /** This method is called from within the 
constructor to
    * initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. 
 The content of this method is
    * always regenerated by the Form 
 Editor.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" 
  desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {


   setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new   
   javax.swing.GroupLayout   
  (getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);

    pack();
   }// </editor-fold>     
  /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String args[]) {

        Path2_Test1 frame = new Path2_Test1();

        frame.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        frame.setTitle("");
        frame.setSize(400,300);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setVisible(true);
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(4500);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }


            //new Path2_Test1().setVisible(true);
            frame.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        frame.setTitle("");
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        //frame.setResizeable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
 }
 private Color Color(int r, int g, int b) {
    Color c1 = new Color(217,63,49);
    return c1;

 // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
 // End of variables declaration                   
}   
}// end of code
```

The other interface which links to this one is as follows ...
its called upon clicking the "view database" button in the interface above

```
     /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package spackage;

/**
 *
 * @author Eskias.Y
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;



public class Path_5_1 extends JFrame{
JPanel p = new JPanel();

JTextArea textP5 = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane textP5Scroll = new JScrollPane(
            textP5,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Path_5_1();
}

public Path_5_1(){
    super("Triples");
    setSize(400,800);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //set center

    Border lineBorder = new LineBorder(new Color(196,69,36),5);

    textP5.setBorder(lineBorder);
    textP5.setBackground(new Color(200,183,154));
    textP5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textP5.setEditable(false);


    p.add(textP5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(p);

    setVisible(true);    
    }
}// end of code
```

Can anyone please help me as I'm pretty muchmuch stuck here? ??
Thank you in advance....

Comment: This is possible, but unusual. When starting the program, you start the .class file containing the main-method you want to start. You could simply call the main-method of the other class you want to start within the main method you started (but I think you will run into issues since you need multiple threads). You might want to start [reading up on how to use multiple threads within Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for my late response ... Thanks for the solution ... I also think that it will solve my problem ... However for the sake of showing the beta version of my application within the  time frame that I had I went on and removed the main classes from the others and linked them using "card layout" in one main class... and now I'm currently building it with your idea ... Thanks ...and I'll let you know (and post the final code on how to join two main classes ) as soon as I finish ... Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks a lot ... It worked ...